# Using PYCHARM professonal with WSL2 as python interpreter: does not have access to some packages

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have python working on WSL2 along with ubuntu20.04. I then installed miniconda and  then,  also installed all common data package, such as: tensorflow, pandas, scikit-learn, matplotlib, sqlalchemy, seaborn pip git

Everything is working fine.

I also have PYCHARM professional installed and as a python interpreter, I am using WSL2(ubuntu20.04). When I try to run the same code that rans fine from WSL2 terminal, PYCHARM complains about unresolved reference to "sklearn" and offers to download that package.  Two questions:

i.  Should not PYCHARM has access to whatever packages are available from WSL2/Ubuntu20.04 terminal, as I am using WSL2 as the PYTHON interpreter?

ii. If I let PYCHARM download package regardless, would not it create duplicate packages that could be possibly different versions?

```
# import the necessary packages
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
```

I am also attaching python interpreter screenshot to show that I a doing it correctly.[image]

UPDATE:
based on @batuhand suggestion, I would like to try using the virtual enviroment. However, the problem is that WSL interpreter is not available.

When I choose WSL interpreter, then \usr\bin\python3 is available.
[image]

When I choose virtual environment, \usr\bin\python is not available.
[image]

So, it seems that I can not follow @batuhand 's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @PavelKarateev. He pointed out to me on JetBrains.com that my interpreter was pointing to /usr/bin/python3 and I have point it to current location. This in my case is:

wsl://UBUNTU2004/home/$USER/miniconda3/envs/PipInConda_DKU/bin/python3.

Here "PipInConda_DKU" was the virtual environment that I created inside the Conda. As the name suggest, I was also using pip to install some package from Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me on WSL2 + PyCharm + poetry :)

Comment: @Nickon , how did it help you with that? I'm struggling with the same issue, and would be grateful if you could share from your experience: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205270/how-to-configure-poetry-environments-in-pycharm-with-windows-wsl2

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual environment for each project in pycharm. If you do that, all you have to do is install packages with pip in pycharm terminal and you will not see any duplication error.

Comment: Please refer to the updated part of my original post. I tried your solution. However, that was not possible.

Comment: PyCharm cannot create venv using Python from WSL as a base. The idea of creating a venv in Windows file system using Python installed on Linux in WSL sounds somewhat controversial at minimum in the first place.

Comment: Creating a venv **inside** WSL using WSL-based Python as a base sound more reasonable to me. Unfortunately, PyCharm is not capable of doing it at the moment (2020.3.1). One has to create a venv manually and select it as a project interpreter in PyCharm.