# How to Configure Poetry Environments in Pycharm With Windows + WSL2?

Tags: python, pycharm, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, python-poetry

**TL;DR:** can't configure a Python Interpreter on PyCharm (Windows) using an existing Poetry environment in WSL. When trying to set the Poetry environment path under `Add Python Interpreter > Poetry Environment > Existing Environment`, the needed Python executable simply does not show. What am I doing wrong?

====================================================

**Details:** 
 
I'm using PyCharm Pro 2021.3 on Windows 11, with Python running on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04). I am trying to add a python interpreter for an existing Poetry environment I created on WSL2, and it just does not seem to work.

PyCharm's current support of Poetry is via [adopting](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#poetry-support) this [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14307-poetry). From what I could gather from the plugin's [official documentation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14307-poetry), in order to define an interpreter with an existing Poetry environment, I go to `Python Interpreter > Add > Poetry Environment`, choose `Existing environment`, and put in the path to that specific environment:
[image]

In order to find the path to that environment, I run "[poetry env info](https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/#displaying-the-environment-information)", which gives a path in the following pattern:

`\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\$USER$\.cache\pypoetry\virtualenvs\my-pretty-project-<some-hash>-py3.8\`

When running `which python` in the environment, I see the python executable is at:

`\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\$USER$\.cache\pypoetry\virtualenvs\my-pretty-project-<some-hash>-py3.8\bin\python`

However - when I browse to that location in PyCharm, the Python file simple does not show. The `bin` directory appears as empty - as also described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65413557/using-pycharm-professonal-with-wsl2-as-python-interpreter-does-not-have-access) question. However - and similarly to what described in [said question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65413557/using-pycharm-professonal-with-wsl2-as-python-interpreter-does-not-have-access) - if I try to redefine the default interpreter path for WSL to be the path to that Poetry environment, the Python executable is there and kicking:
[image]

(The solution described in the aforementioned question, sadly, does not work for my problem, as I am already using the patch to the Poetry environment).

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Posted this at jetbrains.com, too: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4411976832402-How-to-Configure-Poetry-Environments-in-Pycharm-With-Windows-WSL2-

Comment: In the python version that poetry is pointing to (in my case it was python3.9) do you have pip installed? If you have pip installed, IDEA will look for site-packages, and add all to classpath. All dependencies are discovered for me from windows

Comment: Before, when I did not install pip using python binary inside the virtual env with get-pip.py, IDEA was not able to recognize the poetry dependencies. We seem to need pip (in the virtual environment) despite using poetry just to make IDEA work.

Comment: This is probably related with cache-dir path, it tries to reach reach default python installation, try to set cache-dir in your enviroment rather than having it under USERS https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/

Comment: This url talks about connecting WSL python on VScode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/web-frameworks. Don't know if it will help with pycharm, but could help.

Comment: This just in: 
Jetbrains claim PyCharm 2021.3 now has "support for Poetry virtual environments". Together with quite a few mentions of WSL in the [release notes](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/PY-A-231211170), perhaps this means the issue had been addressed?

Comment: I literally just got this to work today, but it was a chore. When using WSL you may not get all the options for environments as shown above (this is with 2023.2) and I found that for my use case (AWS CDK apps with Python under _pyenv_ and _pyenv-virtualenv_), getting all the moving parts to play nice (PyCharm+WSL+Poetry+Pyenv+CDK) was a frustrating, but eventually successful, endeavour. Will try to provide the Answer, if interested, and once I've used the pattern for a few projects

Comment: @Marakai would be great if you shared how you solved it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" it by setting `Add Python interpreter => WSL => Python interpreter path:` to

`/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-name-1yjHsXUg-py3.10/bin/python`

The path above is the poetry environment obtained by

```
$ poetry shell
$ which python
```

Answer (score -2):

Let me get this straight: You want PyCharm for Windows to execute Python binaries in WSL?

That cannot happen.

Binaries in WSL are "ELF" binaries which Windows cannot execute (outside WSL). If the virtualenv was created by poetry from within WSL, it will contain ELF Python binaries. And that is why PyCharm for Windows won't ever pick it up. Because ultimately PyCharm for Windows relies on Windows to execute the binaries, *as long as you don't choose the WSL option*.

Explicitly selecting the "WSL" option indicates to PyCharm that for this particular virtualenv you want PyCharm to invoke the binaries using WSL.

The solution is either to re-create the virtualenv in Windows, or just use the "WSL" option but you have to manage the poetry manually via WSL shell.

Comment: That is not correct! PyCharm offers WSL integration and will execute the "right" executables in the correct environment. WSL communicates and runs with either HyperV or (preferably) Docker and you *can* get them all to play nice, as per my comment above.